# Why I have all tasklets in StarPU with the same process ID returned by getpid?

Tags: c, process

I'm modifying hello world starPU on macos (https://starpu.gitlabpages.inria.fr/ ) example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <starpu.h>

void hello_world_cpu(void *buffers[], void *cl_arg)
{
    int pid_t = getpid();
    printf("My pid %d\n", pid_t);
}

struct starpu_codelet hello_world_cl = {
    .cpu_funcs = { hello_world_cpu }
};

int main()
{
    if (starpu_init(NULL) != 0)
        printf("Failed to initialize Starpu.\n");
for(int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
{
    starpu_task_insert(&hello_world_cl, 0);
}
    starpu_task_wait_for_all();
    starpu_shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

And getting

```
My pid 86531
...
My pid 86531
```

Which is suspicious I thought STARPU would send tasklets to different worker processes.